# get owning object of a function javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is more of a general question. I have seen some answers related to it before but none gave me a clear answer.

I want to achieve an auto binding function.

example:

```
var someObject;
var handle = function(arg1, callback){
   someObject(arg1, callback.bind(???owner of callback???))
}

var handler = new Handler();    

//Calling it
handle("my arg", handler.handlerFunction);
```

I'm not able to control the someObject way of calling the callback as it is a third party library and it is calling my callback with a reference to itself, so I can't use this inside my prototype definitions.

I can easily achieve this by using an extra argument to the handle function sending in handler and binding to it.

Or wrapping the handler.handleFunction into an apply block, but I think it would look much better if I could just call it the way I referred to to in the codeblock.

Is it possible to find the reference to the object owning handlerFunction?

I'm using Nodejs, if that has any relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the way you want to call it doesn't work. Here is why:

When you call `handle(handler.handlerFunction)` the argument you pass is a reference to a function. Any information about handler is lost there. You could do this instead:

```
handle("my arg", handlerFunction.bind(handler));
```

Or this:

```
handler.handlerFunction = handler.handlerFunction.bind(handler);
handle("my arg", handler.handlerFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I guess I'll have to go with one of the other approaches. It just feels unnatural having to pass in the handler to the handlerfunction since it is allready defined in that object.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply nothing like that in JavaScript for some good reason.

Instead, as you already mentioned, pass in a context variable and apply your callback to it so that it runs in the owners context. This is commonly used in many frameworks etc...

Comment: Hi, I understand that passing in a context object may be a common approach, but as I commented on Tibos answer, it feels unnatural to actually pass in the handler back to the function which in turn is defined inside handler.